# Can we transfer the charge on a plate of a capacitor elsewhere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, charge

I know it is hard , but can we transfer the charge on a capacitor plate elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you touch it with another (conducting) object the charge will spread over both objects. The proportion of the charge each object gets depeneds on its capacitance.

If you're asking can you transfer *all* the charge from the plate and transfer it to some other object, the answer is that you can't do this with some external source of power. If you imagine your plate and the other object as forming the plates of a capacitor, there is a potential difference on this capacitor due to the charge separation. To transfer all the charge you need a potential difference in the reverse direction. Just connecting the plates will allow the potential difference to fall to zero, but you need to apply an external voltage to generate a potential difference in the other direction.

Comment: can you tell me please how can you transfer a negative charge from the negative charged plate to a metal rod for example?